# php match a string from other string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string as `$test = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee'` and other string as `$match='cc'`. I want the result as `$result='aa,bb,dd,ee'`.
I am not able to get te result as desired as not sure which PHP function can give the desired output.

Also if I have a string as `$test = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee'` and other string as `$match='cc'`. I want the result as `$match=''`.   i.e   if **$match** is found in **$test** then **$match** value can be skipped

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$test   = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee';
$match  = 'cc';

$output = trim(str_replace(',,', ',', str_replace($match, '', $test), ','));
```

or:

```
$testArr = explode(',', $test);
if(($key = array_search($match, $testArr)) !== false) {
  unset($testArr[$key]);
}
$output  = implode(',', $testArr);
```

Comment: The second solution is better :)

Comment: Can you please help. For the same code, If the result needed is as 
$test = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee' and other string as $match='cc'. I want the result as $match=''  i.e  if it matches the string then the $match variable can be made empty or can be skipped

Comment: Meh, I think he just wants `$match = '';` inside the if condition. (on the second solution, I mean)

Answer (score 3):

Try with `preg_replace`

```
$test = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee';

$match ='cc';

echo $new = preg_replace('/'.$match.',|,'.$match.'$/', '', $test);
```

#### Output

```
aa,bb,dd,ee
```

Comment: what if `cc` located at the end? `aa,bb,dd,cc`

Comment: ^^ `"/$match,|,$match$"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $test = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee';
 $match='cc';
echo trim(str_replace(',,', ',' , str_replace($match,'',$test)),',');
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/yH0I98Ns)

Comment: `$match='aa'` will give you `,bb,cc,dd,ee'` - look at my answer - there is `trim` method involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$test = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee';
$match = 'cc';

$temp = explode(',', $test);    
unset($temp[ array_search($match, $temp) ] );
$result = implode(',', $temp);

echo $result;
```